# Matlab Timer function to plot a function

Tags: matlab, plot, timer, visualization

I have three functions which are in turn called by the main function where the end result is a moving color plot of a sine (or any other) function. The main function does this via a timer object.

I am able to create a static plot but cannot get it to update based on the value provided in my timer object.

I get the following error message:

> Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-19'
>   Invalid or deleted object.

The code for the main window is as follows:

```
clc; clear all;  close all;    
rows = 1;
cols = 30;    
t = timer('StartDelay', 0.05, 'Period', 0.05, 'TasksToExecute', 1000, ...
          'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate');
t.StartFcn = {@window, rows, cols};
t.TimerFcn = {@window_timer};
t.StopFcn = @(x,y)disp('end');    
start(t)
```

Code for the function called by the timer function:

```
function window_timer(obj, event)
    imgh = get(obj,'UserData');
    myMat = get(imgh,'CData');  

    myMat = myMat_new(myMat);

    set(imgh,'CData',myMat);
    drawnow;
    pause(0.02);
    set(obj,'UserData',imgh);
end
```

Finally, the function for replacing random matrix values with the sine function

```
function [ myMat ] = myMat_new( myMat )    
    x = -pi:1/10:pi;
    myMat = sin(x);        
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know it's not running. Based on your code, the "new" image data is going to look the same as the "old" image data because `myMat_new` always returns the same output

Comment: So the idea is that the graph should display an updating color mapped sine wave until the program exits the loop. Since I am not seeing the "moving" graph I can say that the code doesn't work.

Comment: You're not updating the data though. You're simply replacing with the same data every time

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your timer the 'obj' is created so this line of code is valid:

```
imgh = get(obj,'UserData');
```

but I don't see any part showing that imgh has a property 'CData'. imgh in your code is a timer object and not a graphic object.

Comment: The second line of the "window_timer" function shows that imgh has the 'CData' property.